# Excel Pivot Table - Percentages with common denominator

Tags: database, excel, pivot-table, percentage

I have a database with error codes in it from a production line. Something like this

---

Code - Line - Date - ErrorQty
E1 - Line 2 - 01.01.2001 - 7

E1 - Line 1 - 01.01.2001 - 1

E2 - Line 1 - 01.01.2001 - 2

E2 - Line 2 - 01.01.2001 - 3

E1 - Line 1 - 02.01.2001 - 7

E2 - Line 1 - 02.01.2001 - 4

E1 - Line 2 - 02.01.2001 - 5

E2 - Line 2 - 02.01.2001 - 8

---

For each Line / Day combination I have a total. Lets say 100 each day.

I need a format where the pivot can calculate the correct percentage even if I group/consolidate the data to say all errors or all lines or months.

At the moment I am only able to have it at the code/line/day configuration, otherwise my totals also sum up and I get a kind of average percentage.

For example line 2 on 02.01.2001 I have 5 and 8 and a total production of 100.
So I have E1 = 5% and E2 = 8%  -- Total = 13%, but in my current configuration I duplicate the total so I get 6.5%

Any thoughts?

---

Addition:

So you can see the duplicated Totals. This is the total for the Date/Line

[image: Data Source]

[image: Pivot Field]

---

Update

Now I finally have the Rep to add a hyperlink, here is an example file.

In the Pivot for Line 1 it has a total of 0,28% - but this should be 5,01% (the summation of the percentages). I know this needs re-configuring to work but I cannot work out how

So it needs to add up the percentages for the grouping of error codes, but calculate cumulatively for all other factors.

[Example file on GoogleDrive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uvvexhZDImJ2hfz6qWgN-hIxHXhlDK3DuICRMVFTdPc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You need to show your current configuration.  Also, if your "ErrorQty" is a percent (or if your "total" is always 100, and ErrorQty is a count), then just SUM them.  If it is not a percent, then how are you calculating the percent from the data you supply?

Comment: I have added some images of how I do this at the moment.

Comment: @witchchild As pnuts wrote, add a column in your source.  There are issues with pivot tables, consolidations, and calculated fields that are best dealt with that way.  I understand that there is a Power Pivot option in Excel 2010+ that may deal with this problem, but I have 2007 so cannot advise.

Comment: @witchchild The way your data table is set up, since the Totals cells do not relate to the individual line, it's not clear to me how that would fit into a Pivot.  I still think the best option would be to add a column calculated as errors/totals for each line, and use that in your Pivot.

Answer (score 0):

In the Values section of the PivotTable pane, click on the item you want as a percentage and select `Value Field Settings`. Select whether you want the percentage based on `Sum`, `Count`, or some other method, then click on the `Show Values As` tab on the form.

The drop down here will give you a lot of summarizing options. Some examples

1. `% of Grand Total`: Provides the item's % of all items in the Pivot Table, regardless of grouping
2. `% of Column Total`: Performs item's % of all items in the same column of the Pivot Table, regardless of grouping
3. `% of Parent Row Total`: (I think) Performs item's % of grouped items. (I think this is what you are looking for)

There are a lot of other options, and they are quite powerful, but will need some experimentation to make work with your data.

Comment: I agree, it's vague. The hope is that opening this feature up to OP, with all the options that are available, that OP can experiment and maybe find something else that will work.

Comment: Using Totals could work if I included the "good" output in the qty field, until you filter by an error code. For example if we have on 1 day on 1 line 100 units produced, 90 are good, 5 have error A1 and 5 have error A2 then i would get 90%,5%,5% respectively. If i filtered out A2 I then get 94,7% and 5,26% which would be incorrect